# Where to place application files in embedded linux deployment?

Tags: embedded, directory-structure

I'm building a control device that runs Debian Jessie on a ARM based Linux SBC. I'm curious what the recommended location is for application files? To date, I've been placing things in a root level directory, e.g.

```
/MyApplication
```

But I was toying with moving it to `/root/` since it's a single user deployment, e.g.

```
/root/MyApplication
```

I know if I was on a more conventional multi-use(r) system, I'd place it in `/usr/local/` or maybe `/opt/local/`. But I'm think that perhaps the guidelines/practices might be different for embedded single use devices?

Comment: [This article on Wikipedia might be a good thing to read.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly you have tighter control of the environment on an embedded system than you do on a desktop or server, and you can probably get away with putting your files anywhere you like (subject to constraints like avoiding read-only filesystems, which embedded systems often have).

That being said, I would definitely avoid `/root`. That's `root`'s home directory and application files that belong to the application and not to the system administrator emphatically do not belong there.

On an embedded system, `/MyApplication` is probably just fine. It has the advantage of being obvious to anyone who inherits management of the system. `/usr/local` and `/opt/local` are fine too, but they lump your application's files together with any other software that might be installed in those directories (which might occur because it's not packages with the operating system distribution). I would consider `/opt/MyApplication` as an alternative to `/MyApplication`, but not with any very strong preference.